# AngualrJS DEV mode using 1069 request in an ERP web app and crashes Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

We are using AngularJs since 2016. There is now way to change it using Webpack, when actualy just it 20MB we are downloading in the DEV mode, but we have using Bower plus we inject into the HTML about 1000 and in total 1069 on loading requests.
The pain is that with Firefox it works without any problems.
Do you know how you can give cache or tune something on Chrome to make it work?